# How to show the node's label when the mouse is over the node in Arbor js

Tags: javascript, html, json, arbor.js

I am using Arbor Javascript to display a graph of nodes and edges. In the graph, I would like to show the node's label as soon as the mouse is over that node. Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="viewport" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000, 400,1);
sys.parameters({gravity:true});
sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport") ;
var node;
var label_node= "Javascript";
node = sys.addNode('The first node',{'color':'red','shape':'dot','label': label_node});
```

Let's suppose the node is created. How can I show the name of that node which is `label_node` as soon as I move the mouse over that node. Could anyone please provide me with the codes to do this part. Your assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like that should work to get the event of mouseover the node:

```
var that = {    
       initMouseHandling:function(){

        // no-nonsense drag and drop (thanks springy.js)
        var dragged = null;

        // set up a handler object that will initially listen for mousedowns then
        // for moves and mouseups while dragging
        var handler = {

               dragged:function(e){
                    var pos = $(canvas).offset();
                    var s = arbor.Point(e.pageX-pos.left, e.pageY-pos.top)
                    dragged = particleSystem.nearest(s);
                    if (dragged && dragged.node !== null){
                       // while we're dragging, don't let physics move the node
                       dragged.node.fixed = true
                    }

                    //ADD WHERE YOU WANT TO SHOW THE LABEL

                    return false
               }
    $(canvas).mouseover(handler.dragged);
  }
}
return that
  }
```

Hope that helps